# UK Visitor visa - will previous history count in my favour?

Tags: visas, uk

Background:

I was refused a UK visitor visa in 2015; due to the ECO having difficulty believing my partner was a legitimate person who I was visiting (Signatures on docs did not match) & that because I was spending so long there (4 to 5 months) they were not satisfied I had funds.

I cleared all that up in my subsequent application and was granted a visitor visa later that year.

Since then, I have had three additional visitor visas approved without incident and always mention the refusal on each application.

My last visa was in 2021 - which was approved.

I have also had a visa for Greece and still hold a valid visa for the US - which was issued in 2019.

I have of course mentioned this on my application and provided details for each visa.

I have never overstayed or broken any rules on any of the visas.

I've now applied again for a visit in July of this year for three week - as we are visiting family (My wife is a British citizen and stays with my in my home country) - we have an 11 month old son now, which we are taking to the UK on this visit.

The one difference here; is that I had a large amount of money come into my account, from my company as a bonus. I attached the pay slips, bonus letter and bank statements. So it's very clear where that money came from. It's 3 x my salary amount. This is the money I am using to fund the trip - I did not state it explicitly - but just stated I had 4000GBP as savings to fund the trip - which is the bonus money I was paid.

This is the part that worries me. I hope they don't see it as funds parking or disregard it as money not accessible to me. It's in my main banking account and I can prove and have proved where it came from.

For whatever reason; I am nervous about the application. Maybe it's because I listed my son who I am traveling with now  or the above bonus - never the less, I am nervous.

Will the UK government consider the previous travel? I hope it will demonstrate that I am a genuine visitor and have a good track record.

And will they take issue about the large amount of money in the account, close to visa application?

Comment: We can't really answer this. But I'd say you sound in pretty good stead here - it's not funds parking, it's evidenced money that you have. You've had plenty of opportinity to sneak off in a wealthy country and haven't done so.

Comment: Previous trips and a history of adhering to visa conditions *and* UK immigration rules will be part of the decision-making process. Sounds like you are suffering from typical post-application / pre-decision anxiety

Comment: @Traveller - That's exactly it. I guess I have nothing to worry about. It's just this trip is important to us and "all locked in" can't move it out if we get a refusal etc.

Comment: @RobertJ.Clegg I went through the same anxiety recently with an application for a 2 year visitor visa for my long distance partner, whose situation is far less favourable than yours. It turned out fine. As you seem to have a good reason for visiting ‘regularly’ and have a good history, IMHO next time you could consider applying for a long-term visit visa too

Comment: 3x salary as bonus is not unusual. It will be clear from the bank statements that it came from your employer. No worries.

Comment: Thanks @Traveller - I had considered a longer visa this time rough; however I plan to immigrate to the UK soon (Due to family) so took a short visa now to save on costs. Glad it turned out well for you!

Comment: @AnishSheela - The other issue I was considered about is our son need to get a CoE - Right to Abode to enter UK - I did not want the ECO to deny my visa based on our Son not having a visa yet (Ie how could I travel if my son can't - type of thing)

Comment: You are just overthinking. There is no reason to reject the visa. You have solid travel history to UK, you have money. There is no reason to suspect that you will overstay. Even if there is anything wrong, all you can do is wait till you get a decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cleared up the problem and have been granted a visa to the UK since.
All your travels since have been without problems, and you have done enough for the UK visa not to have been a fluke.

The money in your bank is yours, you have added the bonus letter to all the usual payslips and so on, so that should not be a problem either.

No need to worry about your visa.
Children do usually get visa to travel with their parents when the parents are deemed safe to get a visa, so I think you have no reason to worry about that either.

Comment: My visa was approved and my son's Certificate of Entitlement was also approved.